# Detect changes in nested object with mobx observe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mobx

I have this observable which is a nested object 
`@persist("object") @observable public data: IPlayer | null = null;`

Then I have a GraphQL subscription that triggers whenever there's a change in the DB document. My objective is to check for a change in the `config` object inside the `data` object which is something similar to this:

```
data:{
 bar: {...},
 foo: {...},
 config: {
  identity: {...},
  storage: {...},
  .
  .
  .
 }
}
```

I just want the `observe` to observe changes inside the `config` object. I've tried many things like `observe(this.data?.config, (change)=> console.log(change))`. or `observe(this.data, "config", (change)=> console.log(change))`

I tried aldo `deepObserve` from `mobx-utils` but nothing detectes the changes that indeed happen.

- How can I make it to observe a nested object?
- Can I call the observe inside a class constructor and it'll trigger when a change occurs, or does it need to be in the call stack frequently so it checks the changes? Like in a `setTimeout`

Thank you in advence